# Java xpath selection

Tags: java, xpath

I'm having a little trouble getting values out of an XML document.  The document looks like this:

```
<marketstat>  

<type id="35"> 
  <sell> 
    <median>6.00</median>  
  </sell> 
</type>  

<type id="34">    
  <sell> 
    <median>2.77</median> 
  </sell> 
</type>      

</marketstat>
```

I need to get the median where type = x.

I've always had trouble figuring out xpath with Java and I can never find any good tutorials or references for this.  If anyone could help me figure this out that would be great.

Comment: I really like the XPath tutorial [here](http://www.zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages~List_of_XPaths).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the XPATH side of the problem: this should do the trick

```
//*/type[@id='34']/*/median
```

When I am dealing with XPATH I usually use W3Schools as reference. And IBM DeveloperWorks has a [tutorial for the Java XPath API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with XQuery. To get the median of the type tag with where id is x you can write such a query;

```
for $var in doc('this_file.xml')//type
where $var/@id='x'
return data($var/sell/median)
```

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xquery_intro.asp) for XQuery syntax:

Answer (score 0):

If your unfamiliar with Xpath you can install the FireXpath plugin into Firefox. It's a great way to verify your xpath expressions - and learn xPath.

Answer (score 0):

An other way to select your median node could be:

```xml
//type[@id='34']//median
```

You can find a lot of xpath query sample on http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html